# How to save spatial reference to GeoTIFF created by node-gdal?

Tags: javascript, gdal

I am trying to create a GeoTIFF using [node-gdal](https://github.com/naturalatlas/node-gdal) and set the spatial reference to it. The spatial reference is from an existing file and write the code like this

```
// read an existing file and get its spatial reference
let dataset = gdal.open(filePath);
this.bandData = dataset.bands.get(1);
this.rasterSize = dataset.rasterSize;
this.geoTransform = dataset.geoTransform;
this.spatialReference = dataset.spatialReference;

// save the same spatial reference to a new file
let driver = gdal.drivers.get('GTiff');
let dataset = driver.create(filePath, this.rasterSize.x, this.rasterSize.y, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte);

let bandData = dataset.bands.get(1);
bandData.pixels.write(0, 0, this.rasterSize.x, this.rasterSize.y, data);

dataset.spatialReference = this.spatialReference;
dataset.geoTransform = this.geoTransform;
dataset.flush();
```

However, when I load the saved file with QGIS, it suggests the GeoTIFF doesn't have any projection information.

The full code can be found [HERE](https://github.com/haoliangyu/node-qa-masker/blob/master/src/qa-masker.js#L96).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obviously a typo :-(

```
this.spatialReference = dataset.spatialReference;
```

should be

```
this.src = dataset.src;
```

Comment: must be `this.srs = dataset.srs;`